# How to get iTerm to properly send the CTRL-. sequence?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, iterm, emacs

Emacs uses a lot of `C-.` and similar keyboard sequences.

iTerm doesn't send the key sequence `C-.` itself, but I've found that I can map `C-.` into an escape sequence or hex code or text in iTerm's preferences/profile/keys. How can I get iTerm to send `C-.` as something that Emacs will recognize?

Answer (score 3):

You can view Emacs' key bindings by typing `C-h, b`. If you then search the help text for `C-.` you'll find this mapping:

```
M-[ 2 7 ; 5 ; 4 6 ~ C-.
```

The `ESC [ … ~` sequence is used to send arbitrary key combinations numerically, primarily for combinations that don't map to a specific character. Since Control-Period doesn't map to a character that can be sent to a terminal, map it to the character sequence `ESC [ 2 7 ; 5 ; 4 6 ~` (without the spaces).

The second parameter in the escape sequence is a number representing the modifier keys and the third parameter is the base character. The modifier-key values are described at the end of the *PC-Style Function Keys* section of the [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) documentation.